# Rails & Webpack - not generating public/packs on AWS EC2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webpack, amazon-ec2

I have deployed the **Rails** App on **AWS EC2 instance** using **Rails** and **Unicorn**.

But `rake webpacker:compile` command not generating **public/packs** even **public/assets** is created.

I also tried `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` but it was the same.
Anyone can help me?

Comment: Is the asset precompilation generates precompiled assets in production mode locally?

Comment: Hi @Aarthi, yes it generates precompiled assets properly. Only `public/packs` are not created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could fix by running `yarn upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

If you are on rails 6 >, then do

```
yarn add webpacker
```

else try doing

```
bundle exec rails webpacker:install
```